# Freemarker : Paginate merged PDFs

Tags: merge, freemarker, page-numbering, bfo

I'm currently merging PDF files generated through freemarker in the following way :

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">';
    xml += '\n';
    xml += '<pdfset>';
    xml += '\n';

    pdfs.forEach(function(pdfFile){

        xml += '<pdf src="' + nlapiEscapeXML(pdfFile.url) + '"></pdf>';
    });

    xml += '</pdfset>';
```

Is there any way I can paginate the final file (result of the merged files) using the pagenumber tag?

Comment: This looks like JavaScript and not FreeMarker. FreeMarker can't read JavaScript because FreeMarker is rendered server-side and JavaScript is client-side.

Comment: It's server-side JS.

Comment: The way I merge the PDFs works perfectly. But I don't know how to paginate the merged, resulting file.